# Fill Select in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core I have the following Model:

```
public class ViewModel {

  public Int32? ProductTypeId { get; set; }

  public List<ProductTypeModel> ProductsTypes { get; set; }

  public class ProductTypeModel {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
  }

}
```

And I have the following on the View:

```
<select asp-for="ProductTypeId" asp-items="@Model.ProductTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList()" />
```

The select shows no items. I checked and the ProductTypes list has 12 items.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It should work. Could you show your action method?

Comment: Looks like you have invalid HTML. Should be: `<select asp-for="ProductTypeId" asp-items="@Model.ProductTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList()"></select>`